# apply impulse by angle

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

Good day!
I have a SKSpriteNode rotate like this:

```
    bullet = [SKSpriteNode node];
    bullet.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"bullet.png"];
    bullet.size    = CGSizeMake(30, 40);

    bullet.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize: rocket.size];


    CGPathRef circlePath = CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-35, -35, 70, 70), 35, 35, nil);
    SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:circlePath
                                        asOffset:NO
                                    orientToPath:YES
                                        duration:3.0];

    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];
    [bullet runAction:forever];
```

The question is how to apply impulse in case of current position with touch like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    [bullet removeAllActions];
    [bullet.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:bullet.zRotation];
}
```

}

I'm looking for the direction in which to apply the impulse. And it should be fired from the circle from current point

**SOLVED**

if anybody interesting with this problem

```
    CGFloat radianFactor = 0.0174532925;
    CGFloat rotationInDegrees = bullet.zRotation / radianFactor;
    CGFloat newRotationDegrees = rotationInDegrees + 90;
    CGFloat newRotationRadians = newRotationDegrees * radianFactor;

    CGFloat r = 5;

    CGFloat dx = r * cos(newRotationRadians);
    CGFloat dy = r * sin(newRotationRadians);

    [bullet.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(dx, dy)];
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The direction in which to apply the impulse? Direction with regards to what? Should it fire away from the circle? Towards? As you can see, you did not yet specify enough information for a good answer to be given.

Comment: yes, I'm looking for the direction in which to apply the impulse. And it should be fired from the circle from current point

Comment: So you want the bullet to move in the direction it is pointing?

Comment: not quite. i want the bullet to move like centrifugal force vector.

Comment: Thanks I was trying the same thing, thanks verry much @Pavel